# Is NAT/Port Forwarding Faster than DNS Host Overrides?

Tags: domain-name-system, nat, port-forwarding, pfsense

I have a LAN based site that was setup to resolve via a internal domain like `dev.example.com` via host overrides in DNS resolver (overrides LAN request to `dev.example.com` to `<internalIP:PORT>`). It was fast and worked great. Then we needed to access the site remotely. So i setup NAT/Port Forwarding so that `<publicIP:PORT>` resolved to the `<internalIP:PORT>`. The NAT setup is lightning fast. Access via WAN is good as expected but LAN access is so much faster to that site now.

A request to `<publicIP:PORT>` from the LAN is much faster than request to `dev.example.com` from LAN were and I don't know why. I don't have specific time stamps but its so much faster we noticed it right off the bat and speed wasn't an issue before.

Is NAT/Port Forwarding process Faster than DNS Host Overrides?

Answer (score 0):

dns resolving takes time, but if you put hostname and ip into hosts file - then it should be fast too.

Comment: The reason I didn't go the host file route is because this is a multi-device multi-OS environment. Using host files would be counterproductive compared to making changes in the firewall. Especially since host overrides in the firewall yielded fast results...just not as fast as NAT/port-forwarding.

Comment: so yeah, nat should be faster than resolving dns ;)